# Understanding the TLS/SSL protocol

Tags: security, encryption, network-protocols, ssl

I'm currently taking a university class on security and cryptography, and one of the projects we're doing involves implementing a basic TLS socket.

So, I've studied the TLS protocol using both my textbook as well as the latest [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246), so I have a pretty good understanding of how TLS/SSL works, and also how the TLS record format is laid out, byte-by-byte.

So, to start out I decided to write a server program that listens on port 443 and accepts incoming secure HTTP connections.  All it does is accept a client connection and then print out a hex dump of the initial message sent by the client.

But when I connect to my server using a web-browser (Firefox), I'm totally baffled by the bytestream the browser sends me.  [According to the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2), the first thing a TLS client must do is send a `ClientHello` message.  All messages must be encapsulated in a TLS record format, which is supposed to be formatted like this (using the C-ish notation the RFC uses):

```
  struct {
      ContentType type;
      ProtocolVersion version;
      uint16 length;
      opaque fragment[TLSPlaintext.length];
  } TLSPlaintext;
```

The `ContentType` field is a single enum value that must be one of the following types: `change_cipher_spec = 0x14, alert = 0x15, handshake = 0x16, application_data = 0x17`

So, since the first thing a client must do is send a ClientHello message, which is part of the handshake, I'd expect the very first byte in the bytestream to be a `0x16`, indicating this is a handshake message.

But instead, the actual bytestream my browser sends is:

```
80 55 01 03 00 00 3c 00 00 00 10 00 00 88 00 00 87 00 00 39 00 00 
38 00 00 84 00 00 35 00 00 45 00 00 44 00 00 33 00 00 32 00 00 96 
00 00 41 00 00 04 00 00 05 00 00 2f 00 00 16 00 00 13 00 fe ff 00 
00 0a 00 00 ff 07 99 58 ad 17 f3 17 23 be 63 8c 6d cb 9b 5f 6f
```

I can't make any sense of this bytestream, even after pouring over the RFC for hours.  Everything I read about TLS tells me that the first byte should be a `0x16` to indicate a handshake, followed by a two-byte version field, followed by a two-byte record length field.  But this byte-stream begins with an `0x80 0x55`, which is meaningless to me.

Can anyone clear up what's going on here?  Am I misunderstanding some part of the TLS protocol?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing is the SSL version 2 compatible hello. Look at [appendix E of RFC 5246](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#appendix-E.2). I don't believe the newest versions of firefox will send that, they'll only send the V3 hello format that you were expecting.

Answer (score 5):

Wireshark has a parser for HTTPS/TLS/SSL,  this will be able to make sense of the plain text part of the handshake.

Also make sure to read [The First few milliseconds of an HTTPS connectio](http://www.moserware.com/2009/06/first-few-milliseconds-of-https.html)n.